# Data "dumpification"

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer, data-dump

I'm not one to pester*, so I wanted to put in a polite request for new data to be placed in the Data Explorer whenever there is an opportunity.  I know there are posts saying that the schedule is monthly, but the past couple of times it seems as if the request for the service was welcomed.

As always, thanks to whomever for making this service available!

*<sup>I'll be good, I'll be good and go to bed on time and brush my teeth, I promise!</sup>

Comment: +1 for "dumpification"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

done ... my export engine is getting more robust every month ... I may be able to schedule this as a job soon.

Comment: Thanks Waffles!  I was just going to leave a comment about it. :)